# WCF/RESTful with existing DAL

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, rest

I'm migrating a system to its version 2.0.
It's escalating so I want to build a `WCF`. This is the first time for me working with a WCF so this may be kind of basic, still, any heads up will be very much appreciated.

The existing system consists of a 3 layered proccess.

1. UI based on WebForms.
2. Business Layer.
3. DAL.

For this 2.0 version what I'd like to achieve is to leave webforms behind, moving to a more mvc oriented interface. And, as I've already said, to use some sort of web service to get through in order to connect to my db source.

The question is as follows. I've been investigating and reading about `wcf/restful` and in the Iservice.cs I can see the interface and the `DataContract` with its `DataMembers`. The scratching-head part is that I already have my classes defined on the other layers. So, what is it meant to be done? Should I define my classes inside the `WCF` one by one aswell? Can't I just reference my `DAL/Object` Layer and use the resources available there?
Should I add another proyect to the existing VS2010 solution or should I leave the wcf alone?

I'd love to get some input on best practices also, if you may.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better way will be, add another separate layer for WCF service give DAL reference to it, at the same time also give DAL reference to BAL. And DON'T give WCF project reference to any one because you want it to be RESTFULL (i.e. to be access only through HTTP, ftp like protocols)

Here Iservice.cs is just interface which exposes methods to the outer world, it depicts what data, in what form and where it will be find. just implement that interface to any repository class in WCF project, which further will get data from DAL for you. Buisness Layer is the Only layer who will talk to Service layer.

Adding DAL reference to BAL is only for the metadata of the entities.

If i was wrong kindly revert me.

Comment: Thanks Arun, let me know if I got this the right way. I'd need to create the classes I'm going to use (actually replicate since they exist in my BOL) in a repository file inside my WCF proyect. So this way it can accept the response from the DAL/Business layer.

Comment: ohkk..then that approach will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

If REST is really what you are after, then there are other options for this than just WCF. WCF is generally overkill for most scenarios, so consider looking into:

1. [`ASP.NET Web API`](http://www.asp.net/web-api)
2. [`ServiceStack`](http://www.servicestack.net/)

Both options work with ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET WebForms, although most `ASP.NET Web API` examples will be used with ASP.NET MVC, which is the scenario you want to use it in it sounds like.

You can treat the ASP.NET Web API or ServiceStack as another layer in your architecture and just reference it like you would the business or data-access layers, as separate projects in your solution.

Comment: I think I wasn't that clear. I'm not planning on using asp.net mvc. I meant to head to a more mvc system. The idea is to use let's say plain html pages using Ember and Ajax basically. Think it'll be the more productive and time-cost plan since I'm not that versed in asp.net mvc.

Comment: @DanielSh. - okay, I stand by my answer anyway. Just out of curiosity, did you pick Ember.js over KnockoutJS/BackboneJS/AngularJS for any particular reason?

Comment: Honestly, handlebars. It's the template engine I'm more in touch with and after reading a bit of every plugin you mentioned I got the idea that Ember was the logic choice. I'm kind of on my own since this is a small company and all I do is self-taught reading SO and coding by myself. I somewhat understand the logic behind Ember by now but I'm open to try other ways. Thanks.

Comment: I'm with Karl on this one. Familiarity doesn't get you far if the underlying system is complex and a new system is straightforward. :) FWIW, our organization is moving away from WCF and to MVC for our services, even for services which aren't "MVC." Counterintuitive, perhaps, but there you go.

Comment: @DanielSh. - awesome, good for you. I have not used Ember before, because of time and developing with Knockout-Backbone-Angular already, time is not readily available. A good templating engine makes life easier for sure. :-) Good luck with your project.